# java MySql tablas relacionadas

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

buen dia, ayuda.
estoy trabajando en un proyecto de mysql-java, en el cual ya he realizado ingreso de datos a la primera tabla, pero ahora necesito ingresar datos a una segunda tabla relacionada, necesito el poder capturar la clave primaria de la primera tabla en un jtextfield sin que el usuario tenga que digitar dicha clave, para hacer el ingreso en la segunda tabla.

que metodo debo realizar??

Comment: Cómo es la primera tabla? Cómo es la segunda? Cómo ingresas los datos a la primera? Cómo es el formulario donde está el JTextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conectas con la base da datos y obtienes los ID's de tu tabla en un ResultSet.
Pasas ese ResultSet a una nueva clase que herede de JFrame

```
try {
        // crear conexion
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
        // crear objeto Statement
        Statement state = conn.createStatement();
        // ejecutar sql
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM NOMBRE_DE_TU_TABLA";
        rs = state.executeQuery(sql);           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

En el ResultSet tienes todos los ID's que puedes poner en un JTextField con un simple;

```
JTextField campo = new JTextField();
campo.setText(rs.getString(1)); // si el ID es la primera columna
miLamina.add(campo);
```

Espero haberte ayudado !

Answer (score 0):

por lo que pude entender necesitas consultar el campo clave primaria de una tabla, por ejemplo Venta. El tema es de cuál registro de la tabla, yo supongo que necesitas el último. Después hay que ver con que estás trabajando, capa de persistencia como Hibernate, o jdbc, etc. En ambos casos tenes que hacer la consulta siguiente a la base de datos:
En el caso que sea Venta y queres rescatar el id de la última venta,
SELECT max(v.id) FROM venta v

Pero la verdad no se si respondí a tu pregunta, tendrías que dar mas detalles